# Обобщения рендера (отображения) пачки классов. Снятие ответственности с кода

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, mvc, java, generics

*Сильно изменил первый пост. Проблема не была решена и была лишь отсрочена. Надеюсь на помощь:*

Пишу набор классов. Делаю их в виде отдельной библиотеки. Хочу добиться, чтобы можно было эту библиотеку использовать в самых разных местах и самыми разными способами.

Классы почти не содержат в себе никаких данных-примитивов, которые можно легко отрисовать в Виде. Конечно, часть классов содержат простые данные, но этого недостаточно. Вот, например, один из parent классов:

```
public abstract class Animal{

private boolean alive = true;

public Animal() {
}
//getters...setters

}
```

Вот его наследник:

```
public class Cat extends Animal{}
public class Dog extends Animal{}
```

**UPD**

Как видно, в parent классe информации очень мало, которая могла бы быть использована для рендера. Я хочу составить двумерный массив из этих объектов, и каким-то образов отрисовать их на страницу Jsp, например если класс Кот - то вывести в Jsp ссылку на картинку с котом, если собака то ссылку на картинку с собакой. НО т.к. сами объекты информации не содержат почти никакой (кроме типа), то возникает проблема - как мне в "внедрить" эту информацию. Конечно же в готовые классы я не могу добавлять никаких ссылок на картинки, ибо хардкод.

Мне нужна максимальная независимость. Например:

- чтобы можно было использовать её в DOS консоли (т.е. Вывод информации строками);
- возможность вывод информации в HTML (получается тоже вывод строками - ссылками на jpg, gif, или png);
- рисование картинок + текста на android-кнопках,

Comment: Не совсем понял цель, но можно посмотреть на Unity. Там есть объект, который может содержать модули. И каждый модуль отвечает за определенную функцию, например, есть модуль отрисовки, есть модуль физики, модуль частиц и т.д.

Comment: @Deadkenny нет. никаких движков мне не нужно. Я не делаю чтото сложное. это вопрос по основам.

Comment: Из описания понятен самый минимум. Кот наследует ячейку? Ячейка отрисовывается сама по себе? Почему hitCell, но listener.cellHit? Если нужна независмость на разных представлениях, то это де-факто уже запрет на draw() в конечном классе, должна быть некая сцена и рендеререр, который отличается для консоли и HTML.

Comment: Согласен с @Etki. Один класс - одна ответственность. Не должен объект `Cell` и знать, жив ли он (`alive`), и рисовать себя (`draw()`). Пусть какой-нибудь `ConsoleCellDrawer` выводит `Cell` в консоли, а `CanvasCellDrawer` рисует `Cell` на холсте. Вот эти классы могут даже иметь один интерфейс `IDrawer`.

Comment: @Etki спасибо за то, что указал на быдло-код (методы cellHit-hitCell). Что-то я и не заметил. :-)  
@atwice  Нужно ли мне из класса Cell удалить метод отрисовки? А как тогда отрисовывать, внешним классом?

Comment: @argamidon, добавить интерфейс, который необходим отрисовщикам. Какую информацию они будут отображать?

Comment: @atwice например, на веб-странице, определённый тип должен выдавать определённую картинку. Cell - выдавать пустой квадрат gif, Cat - квадратная картинка с котом. Т.е. основываясь на типе объекта.